# How to hide active firefox tab name from KDE task manager?

Tags: kde, desktop-environment, plasma, kde5

[image: KDE task manager]

I'm trying to hide the `active tab` name of minimized firefox or chromium from `KDE task manager`. (Eg. In above picture I want to hide `Newest kde question` -Unix...')
I'm using `antergos`.

Comment: You should write that up as an answer @dsstorefile1, I would've upvoted.

Comment: Thanks @dsstorefile1 but is there any other way? I kinda like the title bar. Like just list the active firefox as an icon in task manager.